# pedometer is not working in background mode in ios 13 only

Tags: ios13, core-motion, background-mode, pedometer

I have an app that just counting steps in Active State and Background Mode with CoreMotion CMPedometer.

It works fine on ios 12.4.1

ios 13: steps counting doesn't work in Background Mode, but work in Active State.

I haven't any errors and in Active State I get "steps, that I went in background".

I have permission NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

In fact, I do not receive a notification (print in console) that I am moving.

Please help.

Comment: Did you find anything in the past 2 months? Running into the same issue.

Comment: same problem as well, could not do it with BGAppRefreshTask either.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this a little bit and it turns out that the background processing logic has been updated on iOS 13. I see that my steps tracking (CMPedometer) task gets almost immediately killed when the app goes into the background.

You are most likely using `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)` to track user steps and motion in the background. This is now deprecated on iOS 13 SDK and you will need to use `BGAppRefreshTask` to achieve the same functionality.

More details are in the Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application]).